# Batch file to move files and folders in a folder to another folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using the below but it is only moving the files and not the folders in the source folder.Is there anything I can add?

```
move "C:\source\*" "C:\destination\"
```

Comment: you need to use xcopy

Comment: but wont this use copy instead of move ?  i am doing this to move very big video files

Comment: move "C:\source\*" "C:\destination\"   only moves files and not folders

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "source=c:\source"
    set "target=c:\destination"

    (if not exist "%target%\" md "%target%" ) && (
        pushd "%source%" && (
            for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a /b *') do move "%%a" "%target%\"
            popd
        )
    )
```

Ensure that target folder exist, then, if source folder is accesible, change active directory to the source folder, and for each element inside it, execute a move operation to the target folder

Answer (score 1):

This is another way: test it on sample folders first.

```
robocopy "C:\source" "C:\destination" /move /s
```

**EDIT: Robocopy copies the files and then deletes the original, so will take a long time for large files, even if the source and target locations are on the same hard drive.**

Comment: The problem with `robocopy` in this case are the big files (from comments). `robocopy` help states that move operations execute a copy and then a deletion.

Comment: @MCND You're spot on.  I'm surprised too coz the guys who wrote robocopy are cluey.